# java code to remove a particular value from a string with comma seprated

Tags: java, string, csv, split, return-value

I have a value like the below
String original = "109,107,108";

now I have to remove 107 the comma in the front and the back and should get the output of the string like

String new="109,108"

value to be removed can be dynamic. if say I will get the value to be removed from the string from another method.

Comment: what have you tried? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You need to make some effort and show what you have tried - Read the [ask] page

Comment: Looks like the requierement  is clear. So you can start implementing it and come back if you have a specific problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string at the comma, then remove the undesired values and join it again. Here's an example doing this using the Java 8 Streams API:

```java
Arrays.stream("1,2,3".split(","))
    .filter(part -> !part.equals("2"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Also I noticed you have the "CSV" tag in your question. If you plan to parse a CSV it would probably be better use a library like [fast-csv](https://github.com/osiegmar/FastCSV) or [commons-csv](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv) instead. They will be more optimized and also support more complex cases like escapes.

Comment: Thanks Florian..i was trying somethink like this.. https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/java-split-string-by-comma/?utm_content=cmp-true

Comment: @Florian thanks Florian . I was trying somethink like this and got split value..but the they way used streams..seemed to be very advanced.. i will try learning tht.. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Florian You’re certainly correct that we shouldn’t be toxic, to new developers or anyone else.  However, doing an entire assignment for someone who, for all we know, may not know how to code at all, is doing them a disservice and is doing other developers a disservice.  Helping someone eke through a class without ever learning to program tends to create members of the software development workforce whose résumés are deceptive, since they cannot produce anything.  When they are hired based on such a résumé, our jobs become harder.

Comment: Part of being a good developer is learning how to ask questions about the bits we don't understand.  You get to that point by trying things to test your understanding of the topic or issue. At some point you get stuck and ask questions. It's not toxic to ask OP to make an effort first and comeback with a clearer question, one that shows OP has made some effort first.  It's not helpful to OP (or anyone) to do things for them if they are in path to learn a new skill.  A challenge is actually a path to growth in that case.

Answer (score -1):

In case there are multiple duplicate values, here is one way to remove by position.

```
String str = "123,456,123,982,345";
String[] array = str.split(",");
for (int pos = 1; pos <= 5; pos++) {
    String result = removeItem(str, pos);
    System.out.printf("Removing %s at pos %d : %s%n", array[pos-1], pos,
            result);
}
```

prints

```
Removing 123 at pos 0 : 456, 123, 982, 345
Removing 456 at pos 1 : 123, 123, 982, 345
Removing 123 at pos 2 : 123, 456, 982, 345
Removing 982 at pos 3 : 123, 456, 123, 345
Removing 345 at pos 4 : 123, 456, 123, 982
```

- Pass the string and the position (1 based)
- Split the string on the delimiter to create an array of elements
- Create an `ArrayList` of the elements.
- Remove the one at the specified position.
- And join, returning a String.

```
public static String removeItem(String str, int pos) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
    list.remove(pos-1);
    return String.join(",", list);
}
```

If there are no duplicates, then use [String.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))

```
String str = "123,456,423,982,345";
str = str.replace("423,","); // replace with an empty string
System.out.println(str);
```

prints

```
123,456,982,345
```